# Printing out numbers with only specific digits

Tags: java, algorithm, counting

I'm trying to print out the numbers that are below a specific number entered as a command line argument (e.g 430) that contain specific digits (e.g 2 and 3).
So that my program prints only numbers containing 2 and 3 and are below 430, so the answer would be : 2,3,23,32, etc.

I've written a piece of code but for some reason I can't get it to work.
Any help is appreciated !
Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    for(int i=0; i<input; i++) {
        String test= Integer.toString(i);
            for(int j=0; j<test.length(); j++) {
                if((test.charAt(j) != '2') || (test.charAt(j)!='3')) {

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The digit is " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elaborate on what this means - "for some reason I can't get it to work".  What is it currently doing?  I do think that you might want to use the String.contains() method and the && (AND) operator.

Comment: If you're looking for numbers that only consists of 2's and 3's, why are you checking for 0's and 1's?

Comment: Does your code work if you change `int input  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` to `int input = 430;`? Fix that first, before you worry about the rest.

Comment: `x != '0' || x != '1'` will **always** be true. There is no value of `x` that can ever make that expression be false, because it would have to be equal to `0` and `1` at the same time, and that is just not possible.

Comment: Maybe it is more easy to generate numbers from 2 and 3? Of course you would need to find out, how long the number a number like 430 is. "0 and 1" aren't an easy testcase, because "0001" seems longer, and therefor bigger than 430, but maybe is not.

Answer (score 0):

You'll never reach the else block.

```
if((test.charAt(j) != '0')
    || (test.charAt(j)!='1')) {
}
```

Should be:

```
if((test.charAt(j) != '0')
     && (test.charAt(j)!='1')) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code. In your code, why are you checking for 0 and 1 instead of 2 and 3.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int two = 0, three = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {

        String test = Integer.toString(i);

        if (i < 10 && (test.equals("2") || test.equals("3"))) {
            System.out.println("The digit is " + i);
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < test.length(); j++) {
                if (test.charAt(j) == '2') {
                    two++;
                } else if ((test.charAt(j) == '3')) {
                    three++;
                }

            }
            if (two >= 1 && three >= 1) {
                System.out.println("The digit is " + i);
            }
            two = 0;
            three = 0;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, the 0 and 1 were typos instead of 2 and 3.
Your code still generates all numbers containing 2 and 3, not numbers only containing 2 and 3.
I'm not sure how to fix that?